# Xcode project runs on device, but not simulator

Tags: unity, xcode

I built a 2D game using Unity3d 5.1.1. When i build and run the project with iPhone connected, the game runs fine on the device. But when i select simulator instead of device, i get an error :
" does not have an architecture that  can execute" .
I run the game on iPhone 4S, but cannot run on the iPhone 4S simulator. Similarly, i selected iPhone 6, 5 etc and get this error every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Player settings → Optimizations → SDK*, I had to select *simulator SDK*, instead of *device SDK*. That resolves this.